# Jquery run onClick function as separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `jquery` `onClick` function:

```
    $('body').on('click', '#id_name', function() {
...
```

and i would like to execute this function as another function on ajax call (currently this is only `onclick`).

if my `ajax` call is success then:

```
success: function() {
          // then execute top function 
        }
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: you want callback function ?

Comment: So make it a function and call the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you can use `$('#id_name').trigger('click')` in the ajax success callback.

Answer (score 1):

Make the function a named (non-anonymous) function:

```
var someFunction = function () {
    //...
};
```

Then you can use it for your click event:

```
$('body').on('click', '#id_name', someFunction);
```

Or your callback:

```
success: someFunction
```

Or invoke it from therein:

```
success: function () {
    someFunction();
}
```

etc.  Basically once you give the function a name and it's no longer anonymous you can refer to it anywhere that it's in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Create a delegate function and call it separately

for example

```
function mainFunction(){
// Rest of code
}
```

on click call this

```
$('body').on('click', '#id_name', mainFunction)
```

Inside ajax success call like this

```
success: function() {
          mainFunction()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could explicitly trigger the click event. Or even better, outsource your click code in an own function and then you can call it inside your success function. So, instead of

```
success: function() {
    $('#id_name').trigger('click')
}
```

Do better this:

```
function clickEvent() {
    // do something in here...
}
$('body').on(
    'click',
    '#id_name',
    function (eventArgs) {
        eventArgs.preventDefault();
        clickEvent();
    }
);
```

And then you can simply call it into your success callback with:

```
success: function() {
    clickEvent();
}
```